# Connect Faucet to Laundry Hose

Tags: plumbing, water, faucet, plumbing-fixture, kitchen-sink

I have a [pulldown faucet](https://images.homedepot-static.com/productImages/4693cd6b-65e7-409e-b4e9-d1c0b5b01dc0/svn/spot-resist-stainless-moen-pull-down-faucets-7594srs-64_1000.jpg) that I want to connect to a portable washing machine. The wand of the faucet can be removed, revealing a `female 5/8-16 UN 2B` connector.

The laundry machine uses a hose that has both an `internal thread (diameter ≈ 13/16")` and `external thread (diameter ≈ 7/8")`. I believe these are standard faucet aerator sizes?

What is the easiest way of connecting the two? Given the nonstandard faucet size, I'm having trouble finding an adapter (or chain of adapters) to make the two connect to each other.

Comment: I thought standard faucet size is 3/4 pipe.

Comment: @EdBeal: My terminology might be wrong here. I'm referring to the faucet aerator size specifically.

Comment: Ok they do make a standard size adapter that will convert the faucet to 3/4” npt I used to have them for filling my water bed, they also had them in quick disconnect versions for potable dish washers that connect to the sink, I got mine at a plumbing specialty store, but today I bet the big box stores have them.

Comment: @EdBeal: I'm a bit confused; I'm looking for an adapter from the female 5/18-16 UN 2B connector to the laundry machine quick connector. Do you happen to have a link to one?